# Unable to connect to slave router, IP address refused to connect

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, ip-address

I am having some difficulties trying to log in to my slave D-Link router (DIR-605L). An Ethernet cable is plugged in my laptop to an Ethernet port, as well as another cable connecting the router from another Ethernet port to the master router, leaving the Internet port open (on the slave).

I have tried entering both `http://dlinkrouter.local/` and `http://dlinkrouter/`; I have also tried entering the IP address `192.168.0.1` into a web browser and logging in from there, it didn't work apparently.

I went to the command prompt and entered in

```
$ ipconfig /all
```

to find all the relevant IP addresses, they are as follows:

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 20-89-84-20-51-87
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2a01:e35:2ebe:f2c0:b410:7db7:dac8:38d6(Preferred) 
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2a01:e35:2ebe:f2c0:8c44:41f7:5f8d:1565(Preferred) 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b410:7db7:dac8:38d6%19(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.32(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Friday, 18 August, 2017 15:05:07
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, 19 August, 2017 3:05:07
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::f6ca:e5ff:fe4d:eb3%19
                                       192.168.1.254
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 52464004
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1C-95-5B-F1-20-89-84-20-51-87
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

`192.168.1.32` refuses to connect (according to my web browser) and `192.168.1.254` connects me to the master router.

The reason I need to log in to my router is because I want to update the firmware.

Comment: What happens if you disconnect the two routers from each other, then connect your laptop directly to the "slave" router and try to connect to it then?

Comment: I only get my local IP address: `127.0.0.1/8`. I apologise if I get my terminology wrong because I'm an absolute dunce when it comes to networking, hence I'm following harrymc's answer because it's the most straightfoward.

Comment: That's OK. Do you *know* What IP address the slave router should be using...the one you'd use to connect to and manage it?

Comment: It should be `192.168.0.1` or be able to connect using the address `http://dlinkrouter.local/`, according to multiple guides on how to update a DLink router.

Comment: Then with you laptop only connected to the slave router, manually set the laptop's IP to `192.168.0.15` and then try to connect to the slave router. If it doesn't work, then it's not using the address you expect it should be.

Comment: Yeah, it's not working. How would I find the correct address though?

Comment: Are you ok with resetting it? That be option #1. If that's not an option, you need an IP address scanner. I use Angry IP scanner.

Answer (score 1):

Base on your output, I see that your PC's gateway IP is 192.168.1.254 (the master router). This suggests that your PC is getting its IP from your master router. Your D-link router most likely will not get an IP from the master router because it is not making DHCP request on LAN port.

`Internet --- Master Router --+-- (LAN) Slave Router
                             |
                             +-- PC`

You can't access slave router because your PC will send traffic to 192.168.0.1 via the master router (the default gateway) which will attempt to send the packet out to the Internet.

If you just want to update the firmware, you can first download the firmware to your PC and then update the d-link router w/o internet. Unplug the D-link router from the master router, your PC should get an IP from your D-link router and you can proceed with firmware upgrade.

`Internet --- Master Router   +-- (LAN) Slave Router
                             |
                             +-- PC`

Alternatively, you can also move the ethernet from master router to your D-link router from LAN port to internet (WAN) port. This will cause the d-link router to request an IP from master router and also assign an IP to your PC (hopefully it is not in the same 192.168.1.0/24 subnet). And then your PC can access internet and login to the D-link router at the same time.

`Internet --- Master Router --- (WAN/Internet) Slave Router (LAN) --- PC`

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience, I believe there is a high chance that the following is happening. But first, let me clarify terminology:

I would be refering to the outermost router as R1, and the other (DIR-605L) as R2.

From the fact that your computer's IP is 192.168.**1**.32 and 192.168.**1**.254 is the portal to R1, I can see that your computer is in the same subnet as R1, which implies:

1. R1 handles DHCP for R2
2. R2 only acts as a switch
3. R2's portal address is probably on a different subnet

---

So I would recommend:

1. Download the firmware you want to update. You will temporarily lose your internet connection during this process.
2. Disconnect R1 to R2, then hard restart R2. This would usually trigger R2 to enable its own DHCP.
3. Run ipconfig again. I would expect your computer to report a different DHCP server, specifically 192.168.**x**.y where x is not 1.
4. If so, go to this address in your browser and you should be at R2's portal. You can update the firmware at this point.
5. After updating firmware, reconnect R1 to R2, then hard restart R2. You should regain your internet connection.

---

This would usually work, although there is a slight chance that R2 does not enable its DHCP when disconnected from R1. In that case you will have to figure out the address of R2 (somehow), assign a static IP address to your computer in the same subnet as R2, and then accessing the portal through browser. A home router's default address is often 192.168.0/1/2/3.0/1, although there is no guarantee.

If you still cannot figure out the IP of R2, I'm afraid you will have to perform a reset of R2 and reconfigure it. Hopefully you don't get to this point.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer and the main router are on the segment `192.168.1.x`,
while the D-Link is on the `192.168.0.x` segment, so they cannot communicate.

What you should do is:

1. Disconnect your computer from the master router and connect it directly to
   the D-Link.
2. Reboot the D-Link and then the computer.
3. Use `ipconfig` to verify that your computer now has an IP address of
   `192.168.0.x`. If it does, continue to step 5.
4. Give your computer a static IP address of, say, `192.168.0.10`
   and reboot.
5. Enter in your browser the address of `http://192.168.0.1` to get into
   the configuration page of the D-Link.
6. Position to NETWORK SETTINGS, then to SETUP.
7. Set Router IP Address to, say, `192.168.1.250`.
8. Ensure that all checkboxes relating to DHCP are unchecked.
9. Click Save Settings.
10. Reconnect your computer as before, undo Step 4 if required, then reboot.
    The D-Link is now on your network segment. If not, then reboot it.

For good measures you could go into the setup page of the master router and
ensure that `192.168.1.250` is outside of the addresses that are attributed
by it, to avoid conflicts of IP addresses.

In the future, you will connect to the D-Link via `http://192.168.1.250`.

For the D-Link to truly be setup as a slave, it must be connected to the
master as LAN to LAN.
You will find more explanations in
[this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/936062/expanding-wireless-coverage-what-are-the-differences-between-lan-to-lan-and-lan),
as illustrated here:

[image]

Comment: When I disconnected the slave router from the master, connecting the computer to slave doesn't give me `192.168.0.x`, only `127.0.01/8`. Adding a static IP address doesn't work either, when I rebooted it didn't change at all.

Comment: The D-Link seems simply not to be working. Try to factory reset it as [described here](http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/support/faq/routers/mydlink-routers/dir-605l/how-do-i-reset-my-router-to-factory-default-settings).

Answer (score 0):

I always update the firmware of my second and third routers while connected to the others, no hassle.
If you ensure, that only ONE (!) of your routers has DHCP server running to serve IP-addresses it shouldnt be any problem.
So they are all on the same network and see each other.