# Cascading two routers into the same subnet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, wireless-router, nas

There are two routers opeating in my house, the first is ASUS RT-87U, which is the **primary router**, and the second is D-Link DIR model, which is the **secondary router**. It is connected to the primary router through an Ethernet cable (Primary: LAN Port 2, Secondary: WAN Port).

The reason I have a secondary router is because I use it for VPN connections, ie. ExpressVPN (L2TP Protocol).

**My problem is** that I want both routers to be on the same subnet. Ideally, if I wanted to cast something through chromecast (assuming chromecast is connected to a different router that the one my device is connected to), I should be able to.

If I switch to a LAN-LAN setup, I would not be able to connect to the VPN server, which is why I have this router operating in the first place.

I hope my language is clear, and have not mislead anyone.

Thank you.

Comment: If you want the entire house to be on the same network connect via lan ports. See [this](https://superuser.com/a/936639/8672). Otherwise, questions about Android apps are not for our forum.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions harrymc, I've tried this but unfortunately I've lost VPN connection in my secondary router. Is there any solution using the LAN to WAN setup? I've also read that enabling dynamic routing on my primary router can resolve this.

Comment: The secondary router should mostly be used for extending the network. It can do other stuff, but some confusion may occur.

Comment: Definitely, but right now I'm trying to give the option of being able to use a vpn connection and local connection by simply connecting to the desired wifi network. It's not my main goal to extend my primary router network.

Comment: Your problem description needs an update.

Comment: I have edited the question, I hope it's clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't usually control the IP address when connected to the VPN.
The virtual network adapter is configured with an IP address that exists on the
remote LAN that's configured on the remote pool it was configured with.

So normally, you need to control the VPN server to control its IP allocations.

For example, here is an excerpt from the OpenVPN article of
[Assigning a static VPN client IP address to a user](https://docs.openvpn.net/configuration/assigning-a-static-vpn-client-ip-address-to-a-user/):

> By default OpenVPN Access Server works with Layer 3 routing mode. In this mode a private subnet is configured for the VPN client subnet. This private subnet must be different from other subnets used in your networks, and clients automatically get IP addresses assigned from this subnet when they log on. This is automated. Usually it goes in a sequential order until it reaches the end of the portion of the subnet available to the OpenVPN daemon you get connected to, and then it starts reusing older addresses. This acts a little bit like DHCP but technically we don't run a DHCP server in Access Server, just a sort of rough emulation to assign addresses automatically. The subnet that users get addresses from automatically is found in the Admin UI under VPN Settings, Dynamic IP Address Network.
>
> You can set up a second private subnet, a different one, in the VPN Settings page in the Admin UI, in the section titled Static IP Address Network (optional). Set up a unique subnet there and the Access Server will then have a subnet it can use for static IP address assignment.

The procedure described by the above article can only be executed by the
administrator of the VPN server.
If you are not the administrator of the VPN server, then this is impossible.
Many VPN servers do not even have the above feature.