# How do DHCP clients know which of multiple DHCPOFFERS to accept?

Tags: networking, dhcp

Imagine we have a network like in the picture. Six hosts on one layer 2 network, no VLANs. The network is supposed to be segmented into two subnets, with one DHCP server each. The DHCP servers have fixed IP addresses, so they know in which subnet they belong, obviously.

Then new clients get plugged in. They don't know anything about which subnet they're supposed to be in and send their DHCPDISCOVER to the *Ethernet* broadcast 255.255.255.255, so it goes to both DHCP servers. Both servers reply with an offer. Now here's my question: How does the client know, which DHCPOFFER he's supposed to accept?

[image: DHCP situation]

Comment: Compare [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1287263/432690) and answers there.

Comment: Here is another [related question](https://superuser.com/q/1367891/326546).

Comment: "the ethernet broadcast 255.255.255.255" -- That's the IP broadcast address for the local network, not an Ethernet address. The initial DHCP DISCOVER messages also are very likely to use the Ethernet broadcast address ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, but those really aren't the same thing.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Simplest answer - first come first served.

If you had multiple VLANs and 10.10.10.0/24 was on a different VLAN to 10.10.20.0/24 - the broadcast wouldn't cross VLANs.

If the DHCP Server was on a separate VLAN to the clients, an iphelper on the routing interface between vlans would direct the broadcast onto the correct location.

In your scenario where you have 2 separate networks within the same VLAN (or lack thereof) serving up different subnets - its a race.

DHCP Serves up using the following transactions:

1. DHCP Discovery (DHCPDISCOVER) - Client Broadcast - "Is there a DHCP
   Server out there?"
2. DHCP Offer (DHCPOFFER) - Server to Client - "Yeah, I'm here and available!"
3. DHCP Request (DHCPREQUEST) - Client to Server "Awesome, Can I have an address please?"
4. DHCP Acknowledgement (DHCPACK) - Server to client "Sure, here's an IP, a     mask, a gateway, some DNS/WINS Servers, a Time Server, and all the other stuff configured for your scope"

All of this happens on UDP Ports 67 for the server and 68 for the client.

As soon as Step 2 is reached - the client will stop "listening" to other DHCP Servers responses - its happy dealing with the first Server to give it some attention.

As a side note - there is actually a well known series of DoS (Denial of Service) attacks which abuse this right.  An attacker plugs in a device which responds and sends out DHCPOFFER packets and then doesn't send DHCPACK out when asked... over and over and over again.  There is also another DoS attack where "fake" DHCP Servers offer out addresses that can't be routed or that conflict with other IPs it's sniffed to mess with networks.

Comment: And therefore the short answer to "But then how do I run multiple subnets on a single Layer-2 segment?" is "**You don't.**" (Yes, there are ways, but it's not something you _should_ generally do. One layer-2 domain = one subnet.)

Comment: Thank you guys, that really clicked with me. I always wondered how this would be possible, but it simply isn't. So the take away is: Have a router / layer 3 switch between subnets or segment with VLANs, am I right?

Comment: In general, yes, you need either VLANs or physical segmentation. Sharing a L2 domain would be doable *only* if both of your DHCP servers were restricted to handling "known" clients (e.g. by list of 'static leases' with allowed MAC addresses).

Comment: I think you could give each DHCP server a whitelist of MAC addresses and control which client gets an address from which server that way.

Comment: @grawity, you can easily run multiple IP subnets on the same layer-2 segment, if the subnets are equal, and you don't care which client gets an address from which subnet. You just have one DHCP server that gives addresses from both blocks, and one router that acts as a gateway for both blocks (with an address in each). Done. Saying just "you don't" is plain wrong.

Comment: Like [the answer from Oddthinking](https://superuser.com/a/1370324/600133) states, the client can full well listen to multiple DHCPOFFERs before deciding what to do. There's nothing to force it to stop at the first. I suppose you wanted to simplify based on what the most common implementations do, but if you do that, at least state what your assumptions are.

Comment: @ilkkachu: Yes, I do that on my own network. I've done it with one DHCP server, and with two. It's still not something that you _should_ do.

Comment: @grawity, I still fail to see your arguments as to why one even "shouldn't" do it.

Answer (score 10):

The [existing answer](https://superuser.com/a/1370193/5224) from @Fazer87 is broadly correct in practice and I recommend upvoting and accepting it. This answer explores a minor detail a little more precisely.

---

Both DHCP servers may respond with a DHCPOffer message.

A DHCP client may accept them on a "first come, first serve" basis. However, it is not required to take that approach.

[RFC2131](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2131) specifies:

> The client receives one or more DHCPOFFER messages from one or more
> servers.  The client may choose to wait for multiple responses.
> The client chooses one server from which to request configuration
> parameters, based on the configuration parameters offered in the
> DHCPOFFER messages.

So, if second DHCP server offered a longer IP address reservation, or offered a time-server where the other didn't, or maybe had a custom field that the client had been programmed to prefer, it may accept the second offer.

Typically, a "first come, first served" approach is going to get you the offer that hasn't been through several hops across devices (BOOTP rebroadcasts) so it is a good protocol to follow if you have no reason to care.

I was on one project where a custom device would prefer a DHCPOffer that included a TFTP server where updated firmware could be found.

Comment: ...or if one server offered an address that the client had already used before and wanted to keep

Comment: @ilkkachu: Yes, in theory, but there are better mechanisms for this (both renewing a reservation before it expires with the old DHCP server, or sending out a DHCPDiscovery requesting the old IP address) so it is unlikely to be useful in practice.