# How to bridge 2 routers with another router?

Tags: networking, router, bridge

I have 2 computers that I want to make them talk to each other even without internet connection and they are connected on 2 different routers. The internet comes from Router A. From Router A there are 2 routers connected: Router B and Router C. My PC is connected to Router B and the Server is connected to Router C.

How can I ping/make the 2 computers communicate to each other by using this network hierarchy ?

This is the network structure I'm talking about:
[image: network hierarchy]

Comment: Yes, you can. I hope that only one router is the DHCP server. And why is Router C not on the same network segment as everything else?

Comment: Router B and C are connected to 2 lan ports of Router A. Pinging from PC to Server returns `timed out` every time.

Comment: Is your intent to keep them isolated in their own networks or to have them be part of the same LAN? Your picture contradicts both options.

Comment: My intent is to make 2 networks. Computers connected to Router A have 1 network, and Router B and C have another network. The picture shows how they're all set up ATM and how traceroute sees the networks

Comment: Is numbering the server 192.168.1.250 a mistake? It isn't connected to any other device numbered inside 192.168.1.x as far as I can tell.

Comment: You are right, it is a mistake. The IP address should have been 192.168.2.250

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have here three network segments : 192.168.0.X, 192.168.1.X, 192.168.2.X,
because probably your network mask is the default 255.255.255.0.

So the communications you are interested in cannot cross over from
one to the other.

I suggest to :

- Let Router A be the DHCP server and disable this feature in Routers B & C.
- You don't need static IP addresses if everything is dynamic,
  but you are going to have them they should be in one segment only.
  The most common is 192.168.0.X.
- Ensure that Routers B & C either use dynamic IP or are allocated
  static IP addresses in the right segment.
- If the routers are connected via cable, ensure that connections
  are LAN-to-LAN, like this:

[image]

For more information, see the post:
[Expanding wireless coverage: What are the differences between LAN to LAN and LAN to WAN when it comes to connecting two wireless routers?](https://superuser.com/questions/936062/expanding-wireless-coverage-what-are-the-differences-between-lan-to-lan-and-lan).

Comment: At the 3rd bullet "Ensure that Routers B & C either use dynamic IP or are allocated static IP addresses in the right segment", what do you mean exactly by "use dynamic IP" ? Their IP from the DHCP Client List of Router A ?

Comment: @harrymc Please stop flagging comments that are correct.

Comment: @DavidPostill: Fine, I changed the wording slightly, now it's no longer correct and you may delete it. Do we agree?