# Connect 2 LAN networks on only 1 subnet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, subnet

I'm not very good with network terminology or with networking in general, so if you are able to answer please make it as easy to understand as possible

I have two networks in my house: one on the 1st floor and one on the 2nd floor - each is from a different ISP. They're both on 192.168.1.0/24 subnet and they're connecting a bunch of wireless routers to each room living 192.168.2.0/24, and I want to only connect the wireless routers together for easy maintenance but without the main routers interfering each other. How can I do that?

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I can't find the answer I need. Thanks!

**Edit:** The main router are ZTE F600W and FPT G-97RG3, all of the wireless routers are Actiontec GT704-WG. And the only I have is more Actiontec GT704-WG routers

Comment: if you don't mind: what is the purpose of having two networks in your house when it would also be OK for all of the wireless routers to be on one?

Comment: See [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/936062/expanding-wireless-coverage-what-are-the-differences-between-lan-to-lan-and-lan).

Comment: The question is very ambiguous. please provide a diagram, or at least how the 192.168.2.0/24 network interplsys with the 2 192.168.1.0/24 ones.

Comment: Alsi, what make and model are the wireless routers,AP's and switches (if any) do you have - this is relevant as some routers like ubiquity have fancy functionality to help, and vlans are useful if available as well.

Comment: Do the wireless routers use the WAN port or only the LAN one? (ie are they acting as routers or AP's)

Comment: How can I draw a diagram?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be possible to add a router to have both access points, however it depends of ISP services permissions And if possible is Being able to manage just additional NAT, VPN, Tunnels And Default Gateways. What is better is to request to have just One ISP to manage both floors.