# Want to access devices between routers

Tags: networking, router, vpn

I have a telco provided DSL Modem/Router on 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0 DHCP 192.168.1.100 thru 150.

I have a 2nd router configured as a VPN Router on 192.168.1.2(WAN) 255.255.255.0, 192.168.8.1 255.255.255.0(LAN) DHCP 192.168.8.100 thru 8.120.  The 2nd router is connected to the Modem/Router via a LAN connection from the telco router to the WAN port on the VPN Router.

There are 2 Roku's connected via LAN to the VPN router I can't access the Rokus from a slingbox app on a wireless client on the DSL/Modem router.  I have to instead be as a wireless client on the 2nd (VPN) router.  Is it possible via a route/firewall rule to allow me to access the Roku's when a wireless client on the DSL/Modem router?

Comment: You must mean that the cable from the modem connects to the WAN port of the 2nd router. This sets up a second network segment. Why don't you connect to a LAN port so everything is on the same segment?

Comment: Yes. . The 2nd router is connected to the Modem/Router via a LAN connection from the telco router to the WAN port on the VPN Router.

Comment: I meant LAN-to-LAN and not LAN-to-WAN. For the difference see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/936639/8672).

Comment: I tried connecting from a LAN port on the main dsl modem/router to a LAN port on the VPN router and rebooted the VPN Router.  The Roku's no longer have internet access in that config.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to add a wireless access point which solves the issue. Other possible remedies were either unlikely due to hardware limitations which prevented flashing my main router with DD-WRT, etc, or were overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, because this question comes up regularly in different variations:

The proper way to communicate between different subnets is to configure the routers to actually act as a router, that is, turn off NAT, enable forwarding, and make sure all devices get proper routes, either by setting them on the gateway of each subnet, or by distributing the routes via DHCP.

In your case, you only have to do this on the second router (which probably already has DD-WRT), provided your ISP's router DHCP either can distribute routes, you make the routes static on the slingbox app, or disable DHCP and run the DHCP elsewhere, for example on the 2nd router.

Yes, that's "overly complicated", but only because "home routers" are preconfigured for NAT on WAN with a single subnet on LAN, and that's also why several subnets in home networks often use a funny setup.