# Can't access secondary router

Tags: networking, router

I don't have extensive networking knowledge so please excuse me if I don't use the correct terminology.

We have a fibre optic Virgin Media router setup as a modem, I'll call this the primary router.

I have this connected via ethernet to an 8 port switch, which provides connectivity to various devices successfully.

Now there's another router connected (I'll call this the secondary router) to this switch via the lan port, it's an asus rt AC68U and is also setup as a router but with wifi enabled.

If I connect an ethernet to this secondary router to my laptop I can access the router's admin page fine but it doesn't seem to work across any other computers on the network?

I'd like to be able access the admin page for the secondary router across the network, which offers a lot more functionality than the primary - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your scheme is `ISP - (WAN modem LAN) - (switch) - (WAN router LAN/WiFi)`, and your PC is connected to switch? If so you must 1) allow admin access to router from WAN (in its settings) 2) know router's WAN address. Anycase try to draw your scheme, best way including addresses and marking DHCPs with their scopes.

Comment: Is each router utilizing a different subnet (`192.168.1.0/24`, `192.168.2.0/24`, etc)? 
 Where `/24` is the netmask `255.255.255.0`, covering IP's from `.1` - `.254`?  It's likely both are using the same subnet (`192.168.1.0/24` , where the admin page would normally be `192.168.1.1`).  You may wish to set each router within the same overarching network (`192.168.1.0/26` [IPs from `.1` - `.62`] & `192.168.1.64/26` [IPs from `.65` - `.126`]).  See [Subnet Mask Cheat Sheet](https://www.aelius.com/njh/subnet_sheet.html)

Comment: Are both routers on the same subnet? Are you plugging into the 2nd router's WAN port or the switch?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/936062/expanding-wireless-coverage-what-are-the-differences-between-lan-to-lan-and-lan

Comment: Thank you for your comments.