# two private network (2 router)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I need to set up two individual **private** network with two routers

**Router1:** (got wan-connection)

```
LAN:
192.168.1.1
255.255.255.0
dhcp range 192.168.1.100-150
dhcp static 192.168.1.129 hw:router:2:xx:bb
```

**Router2** (wired to router1)

```
WAN settings:
Ip assigned 192.168.1.129
Service provider gateway: 192.168.1.1

Lan:
192.168.0.1
255.255.255.0
dhcp range 192.168.0.100-200
```

[example_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLXJs.png)

initially this gives both router/network internet-connection and ip-range, but network2 can access network1's computers. I need to make network2 unable to access network one. I cant figure out how to use subnet to do so

Comment: Change the IP of Router 2 to a Static IP on Router 1 and restart both routers.  They should not see the other router or be able to access the other computers in normal work. If you wish to more physically separate the networks, change out router 1 (likely) for a good VLAN router and set up an isolated VLAN for router 2.

Comment: Thanks, John.
Router2 already got a static ip from router1. (192.168.1.129). 
(I was already thinking of a VLAN-router as plan-b)

Comment: hi, what's the default gateway set in router2？

Comment: `192.168.0.1` is the LAN gateway on router2

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

- Connect one of Router1 LAN ports to Router2 WAN port
- Enable Router2 DHCP server and set its IP range to `192.168.2.x`

The sub-network of Router1 will then use the IP range of `192.168.1.x`
while the sub-network of Router2 will use `192.168.2.x`, where the two will
inaccessible one to the other.

For more information see the post
[Expanding wireless coverage: What are the differences between LAN to LAN and LAN to WAN when it comes to connecting two wireless routers?](https://superuser.com/questions/936062/expanding-wireless-coverage-what-are-the-differences-between-lan-to-lan-and-lan)

Comment: Ive done exactly that. Router2 will still have access to 192.168.1.x computers. e.g: webserver/ipcam/printer on Router1

Comment: Do you mean access to devices directly connected to Router1 such as printer and camera? Is the webserver in question Router1 itself?

Comment: I still had access to devices connected to Router1, as printers and camera. (no the webserver was a computer on `192.168.1.x`)
I did try change the WAN-ip on Router2 (provided from Router1) to `192.168.2.2` (instead of`*.1.129` as stated) but I was not allowed to use an IP outside the subnetwork of Router1 `*1.x`