# How do I connect my NAS to separate LAN's

Tags: lan, wan

*** I use SYNOLOGY DS918+ - HAS 2 ETHERNET PORTS IN THE BACK ***

Hi, I have two LANS 192.168.1.1/24 & 192.168.2.1/24 - In DS918+ there are two LAN ports and I connected them to these 2 LANS.

Under control panel -> network these are my settings:

DEFAULT GATEWAY: 192.168.2.1 (Bond 1)

Manually configure DNS server is checked and points to Preferred DNS 192.168.1.1 - Alternate DNS server 1.1.1.1

Under ADVANCED SETTINGS all these are checked:

Reply to ARP request if the target IP address is identical to local address configured on the incoming interface
Enable multiple gateways
Enable IP conflict detection
Under Network Interface "Bond 1 connected" edit window has ADAPTIVE LOADBALANCING radio button selected

I am able to connect via 192.168.2.101 but unable to find the NAS in 192.168.1.x

BTW, My setup is as follows

MODEM -> Router 1 (192.168.1.1) -> Router 2 WAN port is connected to Router 1 LAN port (192.168.2.1).

All my IoT's are connected to 192.168.1.1 and they cannot ping Router 2 stuff. My NAS is in Router 2 but I want my IoTs (192.168.1.x) connect to my NAS. This is my usecase

Is my configuration correct? Or I need to tweek anything else?

Comment: I don't have a Synology so I cannot verify this. Apparently all you need to do is to *delete* the bond. // A host doesn't have to be a router to be directly connected to multiple networks.

Answer (score 1):

Connect Router 2 LAN port to Router 1 LAN port and disable its DHCP function.

That will make all devices exist on the same network `192.168.1.x/24`
and they will all be reachable.

For explanation, see the post
[Expanding wireless coverage: What are the differences between LAN to LAN and LAN to WAN when it comes to connecting two wireless routers?](https://superuser.com/questions/936062/expanding-wireless-coverage-what-are-the-differences-between-lan-to-lan-and-lan)

Comment: Unless you want your IoT devices separate from your router 2 lan for security reasons, this is the answer: do not have 2 separate LANs. Security reasons may be not trusting the hardware vendor to implant spyware in to their devices and/or being concerned they are leaving their bugs exposed to the internet, particularly with 'cloud' connected devices.