# How to access device on another subnet from computer

Tags: home-networking

**Background**

So this should be easy for some, but I can't figure out how to do it. I have my network configured like this:
[image]

My goal is to connect to "Device B" from "Computer A". Device B has a web interface so allegedly if I was on the same network I could just type the IP address of device B into my web browser and should see the interface.

Device B has an IP address of 192.168.1.119

**Question**

Now how do I set up my network to allow me to connect to "Device B" from "Computer A"? I can see from the first router that the wireless router has an IP address of 192.168.0.108. From searching on SE I found that most do this through adding a new route. Here is my route that I tried:

[image]

So in my mind, I should be able to type 192.168.1.0 into my browser and see the wireless router's configuration page however I do not unfortunately.

Comment: If Wireless Router is set to work in repeater mode, all the devices would be on the same network of the main router.

Comment: @harrymc I guess I am not sure how to set my wireless router up to do so from its settings. It is a Linksys E1000 though

Comment: See https://www.linksys.com/us/support-article?articleNum=143751

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for the suggestion. In my drop down for "Internet Connection Type" I do not have bridge mode listed though. I have: Automatic configuration DHCP, Static IP, PPPoE, PPTP, L2TP, Telstra Cable as my only options. I did just update the firmware as I was at 1.00.00 and the latest was 2.01.03 but still no option

Comment: @harrymc I think I will just get a more modern router. For $20 I can get a way better one that supports bridging instead of fiddling trying to make this ancient one do it. Thank you for your help anyways though!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: You could maybe set it to Static IP (avoid IP conflicts) and connect it LAN-to-LAN to the main router. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/936639/8672).

Comment: You seem to have made a mistake in your route. You say that your wireless router has an IP address of `192.168.0.108`, but you set the route to `192.168.1.0` network via `192.168.1.108`, not `192.168.0.108`. Additionally it is possible that the router restricts access to its configuration page from outside `192.168.1.0` network (this has nothing to do with routing, look in security settings of the wireless router). So try to ping the device `192.168.1.119` from Computer A instead of trying to access the router's configuration page.

Answer (score 1):

To have everything in one network, you need to turn off the DHCP function
of the Wireless Router.

I suggest this:

- In the Wireless Router, set "Internet Connection Type" to "Static IP"
- Give the Wireless Router a static IP such as `192.168.0.250`
- In the main router, adjust the DHCP allocation range to be "2-249"
- If the Wireless Router is connected to the main router via an Ethernet
  cable, ensure that the connection is
  [LAN-to-LAN](https://superuser.com/a/936639/8672)
- It should work now, so all the devices on the same segment and accessible.

[image]