# How to direct all traffic from ISP modem to Wi-Fi router?

Tags: router, isp

I have my ISP router (`192.168.100.0/24`) in the first floor of my house and where all ethernet cables are going to from each room.

Then I have my main TP-Link Archer AX6000 router (`192.168.0.0/24`) in the second floor with WAN port connected to the ISP router in the first floor.

I do have some devices across the house that uses ethernet but they only can connect to the ISP router in the first floor so they get 1`92.168.100.*` IP.

I want to connect the ethernet cable of these devices to the ISP router and then connect it back to the TP-Link router in the second floor so they can have the same subnet of the TP-Link router (`192.168.0.*`) and manage the device from there.

Comment: Sure. It's just a matter of correctly setting up the secondary router. What exactly is the problem? Please edit] the question accordingly and don't forget to add your router's brand/model.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expanding wireless coverage: What are the differences between LAN to LAN and LAN to WAN when it comes to connecting two wireless routers?](https://superuser.com/questions/936062/expanding-wireless-coverage-what-are-the-differences-between-lan-to-lan-and-lan)

Comment: Connect LAN to LAN to get both routers on the same Subnet.

Comment: I apologize maybe i was not clear enough. I have edited the question hope it is clearer now

Comment: I cannot connect LAN to LAN since there is only one ethernet port next to the tplink and i am using it for WAN

Comment: It is not clear what your setup is. You have a router A (192.168.100.0/24) and cables from that router connected to each room. Then you have a router B (192.168.0.0/24) connected to the router A. Then you have some devices connected to router A. What do you want to do next and why? Can't understand that part. Please edit your question and clarify.

Comment: I want all devices connected through ethernet cable from each room to have the subnet of the tplink router.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.

The solution for my issue is to have another cable from the same ethernet port on the wall which TP-Link is connect to, going all the way to the first floor to connect the TP-Link to a switch.

The first cable will go from TP-Link’s WAN port to ISP LAN port.

The other cable from one of the TP-Link’s LAN port to a switch in the first floor then have all of the ethernet devices connected to the switch.