# Cannot access Asus router after setting it to AP mode - router works but interface blocked by tplink?

Tags: networking, router, asuswrt

a little problem here. I bought a new/primary router (tplink) but decided to keep my old Asus RT N66W as a secondary router in a LAN to LAN setup (see here: https://superuser.com/a/936639/675427). I hook everything up and set the secondary Asus router to AP-mode - the router changes IP. Everything looks good - the Asus router shows up in the client list of the primary router (so I know the IP) and wired as well as wireless connection through the secondary Asus router continue to work. (And everything works on the primary too - full internet access, all wireless networks functional).

The only issue I have, is that I cannot connect to the old, secondary Asus router anymore via browser interface after I set it to AP mode. Neither the IP address it got from the primary router, nor `192.168.1.1` work (but both return pings). No matter if I'm wired or not. `192.168.1.1` just gives me a response from the *primary* tplink router, that "Local Management via HTTPS is disabled". I have no problems to access the *primary* (tplink) router.

I'm on linux for what it's worth. How do I proceed to access the web interface of my old, secondary, AP-mode Asus router?