# Cannot change LAN IP address in my router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-bridge

Simply there is no option to change it. I need to change it from 192.168.1.1 to something else

I will share the admin menu screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

I am trying to use this router as a WiFi extender it has been reset to factory settings. It is a WSEE router and model is WUTG13. I have tried to install other software but there is not a single one available for this router.

Comment: Is this router store-bought or was it provided by an ISP?

Comment: It was provided by ISP when I used their service,I didn't return the router when I switched to another ISP

Comment: On your last image "enable universal repeater mode" should do what you need

Comment: I did that, but both routers cannot be on 192.168.1.1 right?

Comment: what is your other router, and how are the two connected? If this one is in AP mode, it should get an IP assigned by your primary router

Comment: You need to disable the DHCP server function of the secondary router. See also [differences between LAN to LAN and LAN to WAN](https://superuser.com/a/936639/8672).

Comment: It is not at all unlikely it cannot be changed. But why change it in the first place? Please elaborate. Why not change the *other* router's IP address?

Comment: There is no option to disable DHCP also

Comment: @DanielB cant change the IP of primary router cuz a whole lot of servers are running on it

Comment: Message by the poster from a deleted answer : "It was pretty simple to bring up hidden menus just use this account when logging in username is `administrator` and the password is `system864`."

Comment: Don't the screenshots show it's currently set to `192.168.1.25/24`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately my answer is that the settings of this router/modem
cannot be modified this way.

Your router is the modem of your previous ISP, which I suppose was
WSEE. It was fabricated by a company called
[Stel Fiber](https://stelfiber.com/) which doesn't exist any more
and its domain-name is actually for sale.

Your ISP has probably installed a stripped-down (or locked) firmware.
Below are the administration screens of the firmware as they are
on your computer compared with the Stel Fiber firmware:

[image]

[image]

The setting you're looking for was supposed to exist in the "WAN"
section of the settings. However, this section is totally missing
for you.

The original name of the router was GPE600. The Stel Fiber support-site
has disappeared, but I have found it in the Internet Archive, with the
idea of somehow overwriting the existing firmware with it:

[image]

Unfortunately, the Internet Archive has only archived the page, but not
the firmware files to which it points. I have tried all the versions
of the website which are found in the Internet Archive, but the download
links for the GPE600 firmware were not archived in any of them.

**Conclusion**: Your router is locked-in to the firmware with which it
came. That firmware does not permit you to set it as an
Access Point. If you can, you may try in the router from the new ISP,
to disable its DHCP server function, in the hope of unifying your
entire internal network. The WSEE router will then supply it
(and the entire network) with a good internal IP, with no need to
change the internal IP of the old router.

If this will fails, then you need to get another access-point,
rather than the GPE600.

Comment: So there is no other custom firmware available? like dd-wrt or others for this GPE600

Comment: No, this model is not found on the DD-WRT routers database. Not every router has the necessary hardware for DD-WRT, and even then it's not been ported to every suitable router.

Comment: Should I mark your reply as the answer or wait for some more days for someone else to comment?

Comment: So this router is basically useless; it cannot flash a custom firmware, cannot be used as a WiFi extender, etc

Comment: I successfully connected both routers; DHCP is turned off but I cannot connect to internet when I connect to the second router

Comment: Have you connected the routers [LAN-to-LAN](https://superuser.com/a/936639/8672) ?

Comment: It is not connected through Ethernet cables, it is connected through WiFi as shown in this video https://youtu.be/SLy2q8VRcBw?si=4jrdrA4hZFcvRUHS

Comment: Add to your post the screens where you have defined the router as access-point. You don't need to keep all your existing screenshots.

Comment: I edited the post and added the screenshots you asked for. If these are not the right screenshots, please tell me

Comment: I would like also the screenshot for the WAN tab. Try setting Channel Mode to Bridged. There are no manuals to be found for the GPE router family, so it's hard to give good advice.

Comment: I have added the  WAN tab screenshots.

Comment: Try setting Channel Mode to Bridged in the WAN tab.

Comment: Still no internet after enabling bridged mode

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150381/discussion-between-adithyan-s-m-and-harrymc

Comment: Do you have anything like a Repeater mode?

Comment: I have enabled Universal Repeater Mode and 
the two router are connected because I can access the second router's admin menu while connected to the primary router's WiFi
and @harrymc can you look at the conversation, I have shared some information there that are too long to say in comments

Comment: According to that information IPv4 doesn't work, but IPv6 does. Try to disable in the router also any DNS or anything that it would do except serve as a repeater.

Comment: I got it working, I just need to manually allocate IP address to all devices. Thank you for your valuable help

Comment: The issue is still there, as when I allocated the static IP, it worked on all devices, but after a router restart, it is not working again. I found this post in askubuntu  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025008/ipv6-is-working-but-ipv4-isnt to temporarily solve the issue in my Linux machine, but I can't get it to work on my Android phone. I don't know if the problem is with the router configuration or the device configuration

Comment: For Android you might find help on android.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to explain exactly where you are with your settings aas it is all a bit up in the air.

I would suggest the current router isgateway and also `x.x.x.1`, the old router no longer issues IPs ( not act as DHCP server) **leave that to the current router**.

Fix you old router to a value within the realm but not one able to be given out by the current router's DCHP server.

You may wish to alter the IPs available to start late or stop short so that you can squeeze in the old router.

Ensure you old router points to the current one as gateway and copy the DNS entries to the old router.