# How to setup two routers seamlessly without having double NAT

Tags: wireless-networking, router, routing, dhcp, nat

I have two wireless routers, a generic one provided by ISP which is GPON ONU/Wireless router and a TP-Link.

I need an upgrade because the generic one provided by the ISp unfortunately has several limitations (no Wi-Fi 6, no Mesh, no in-built OpenVPN server, even the dual band Wi-Fi work totally separeted which create issues with IoT devices which only support 2.4 communicate with other devices at 5Ghz network)

[image: expected network]

Unfortunately I couldn't be able to put the ISP router at bridge mode and do the PPPoE on the new router which would work fine and easier. I'm searching for alternatives like, Static IP WAN connection, Static Routing, VLAN, but I'm no expert in networks because just connect the WAN through the Dynamic IP Mode I'll face double NAT issues (which sucks for games and other services)

If I use dynamic IP in the new router and just disable NAT the internet connection doesnn't work

I checked others similar answers mentioning Static Routing but they seem very too broad. I don't know which routes to create if this is the way to go.

My gateway in the ISP router is 192.168.10.1 and the new router is 192.168.1.1

Comment: As the modem can't do WiFi 6 speeds, it would be better to connect both routers with a faster ethernet cable (if possible).

Comment: They're connected through cable

Comment: Then you need to designate one as the DHCP server, probably the modem as it's not very parametrable, put the the router in bridge mode, and it should work.

Comment: The internet doesn't work putting the new router in bridge

Comment: Try to switch "LAN to LAN" and "LAN to WAN ([link](https://superuser.com/a/936639/8672)), from whichever one you were using.

Comment: I'm am using LAN to WAN. LAN from main ISP router to WAN of the new router

Comment: Try LAN to LAN.

Comment: for LAN LAN My new router doesn't have the option of put the whole router in bridge mode, only the WAN port can be bridged also it doesn't have the option of disable the DHCP server, only put it the DHCP Server mode or DHCP Relay  (When I set to DHCP Relay I lose my new router default gateway and can't access its admin panel no more)

Comment: I still need the new router admin panel to set the VPN, and other wireless stuff, security filters, as long it will be the router of all devices of the house.

Comment: Can you in LAN to WAN do bridge mode and disable the DHCP server? If you can't, then this is a very funny router.

Comment: I can set DHCP Relay using LAN LAN, it works but I can't access the admin of the new router no more only reseting it. I need manage all the network and the clients by the new router, not the old one from ISP. It is not router for expanding the area purposes, I wanna kill the old router and its wireless network, only use it as GPON modem, no more than that.

Comment: What model is this new router?

Comment: TP-Link XX230V 
https://www.tp-link.com/br/service-provider/dsl-router/xx230v/

It has built-in GPON port but is not compatible with my provider that's why I'm trying having a hard time to only bridge the old router

Comment: This seems like a very complex router, not really meant to function as an access-point, so difficult to tell what should be done without hands-on. The general method is [here](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/1603/), if it can be applied to this router.